# $A.util.isempty returns false when no value is present

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I'm trying to create new record through the lightning component but the criteria for required fields is not checked properly.
$A.util.isempty is used to check the required fields but even for empty values this check is not working.I'm trying to preview the App from console log

code:
Application:

```
<aura:application  extends="force:slds">
     <c:Lightningclass10part2Combo/> 

</aura:application>
```

Component:

```
<aura:component controller="Lightningclass10Class" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >

    <aura:attribute name="Attributeclient" type="Bank_Details__c" default="{'sobjectType':'Bank_Details__c',
                                                                   'First_Name__c':' ',
                                                                   'Last_Name__c':' ',
                                                                   'Email__c':' ',
                                                                   'Monthly_Salary__c' : ' '}"/>


    <div class="slds-page-header">
        <div class="slds-media_body">
            <h1 class="slds-page-header_title slds-truncate slds-align-middle"></h1>

        </div>
   </div>

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h3>Please Enter the Candidate Information</h3>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>First Name : </label>
                <ui:Inputtext class="form=cotrol" value="{!v.Attributeclient.First_Name__c}"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Last Name : </label>
                <ui:Inputtext class="form=cotrol" value="{!v.Attributeclient.Last_Name__c}"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email : </label>
                <ui:Inputtext class="form=cotrol" value="{!v.Attributeclient.Email__c}"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Monthly Salary : </label>
                <ui:Inputtext class="form=cotrol" value="{!v.Attributeclient.Monthly_Salary__c}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
            <ui:button class="btn  btn-default" press="{!c.createnewclient}">Create</ui:button>
        </div>
    </aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    createnewclient : function(component, event, helper) {

        //logs
        console.log('create record');

        //getting the candidate information
        var varclient=component.get("v.Attributeclient");


       //VALIDATION

        if($A.util.isEmpty(varclient.First_Name__c)){

           alert('First Name is required');
        }

        if($A.util.isEmpty(varclient.Last_Name__c) || $A.util.isUndefined(varclient.Last_Name__c)){
            alert('Last Name is required');
            return;

        }



        //call the Apex FUnction
       var action=component.get("c.createrecord");


        //setting the Apex parameter
        action.setParams({
            newcliententry :varclient
        });

        //setting the callback
        action.setCallback(this,function(response){

            //get a response state
            var state= response.getState();

            if(state =='SUCCESS'){

                //Reset Form

                var NewClientEntry={'sobjectType':'Bank_Details__c',
                                     'First_Name__c':' ',
                                      'Last_Name__c':' ',
                                      'Email__c':' ',
                                      'Monthly_Salary__c' : ' '};

                component.set("v.Attributeclient",NewClientEntry);
                alert('Record is created successfully');
                    }

            else if(state=="ERROR"){

                alert('Error in calling server side action');

            }
        });
        //check if result is successful


        //add server side action to the queue
        $A.enqueueAction(action);

    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're defaulting the value to `' '`, which is **not** an empty string. It's a string with a single space in it. An **empty** string is a string with 0 length, equal to exactly `''`. You will want to probably write something like:

```
if(!!varclient.First_Name__c || !!varclient.First_Name__c.trim()) {
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @sfdcfox
I'm new to salesforce and was creating a component for the first time. :)